# Override json file values with environment variables docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, jq

Assume that I've a complex json file that is used to configurate my project.

Like the json below:

```json
{
    "apis": {
        "payment": {
            "base_url": "https://example.com/"
        },
        "order": {
            "base_url": "https://example.com/"
        },
        
    },
    "features": {
        "authentication": {
            "authProviders": true,
            "registration": false
        }
    },
    "availableLocales": [
      "en",
      "es"
    ]
}
```

With .Net there's a feature that allows us to override the values based on environment variables.

If I wanted to override the value of apis.payment.base_url I could pass an environment variable: **APIS__PAYMENT__BASE_URL** and the value would be replaced.

Since I'm currently not using .Net is there any alternatives?
This is what I'm using right now, but this does not fit my needs

```
FROM code as prepare-build
ENV JQ_VERSION=1.6
RUN wget --no-check-certificate \
    https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-${JQ_VERSION}/jq-linux64 \
    -O /tmp/jq-linux64
RUN cp /tmp/jq-linux64 /usr/bin/jq
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/jq
WORKDIR /code/public
RUN jq 'reduce path(recurse | scalars) as $p (.;setpath($p; "$" + ($p | join("_"))))' \ 
    ./configurations/settings.json > ./configurations/settings.temp.json && \
    yez | cp ./configurations/settings.temp.json ./configurations/settings.json
WORKDIR /code/deploy
RUN echo "#!/usr/bin/env sh" | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null && \
    echo 'export EXISTING_VARS=$(printenv | awk -F= '\''{print $1}'\'' | sed '\''s/^/\$/g'\'' | paste -sd,);' | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null && \
    echo 'for file in $CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER;' | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null && \
    echo 'do' | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null && \
    echo '   cat $file | envsubst $EXISTING_VARS | tee $file' | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null && \
    echo 'done' | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null && \
    echo 'nginx -g '\''daemon off;'\''' | tee -a /code/deploy/start.sh > /dev/null
WORKDIR /code
```

This was I have a problem that, I need to pass all the json paths as environment variables, to override it correctly. If not, the variables will be replaced with the path of it, only.

I think the best approach would be:

Read the environment variables and create a json file with their values, then override the existing json file with the values of the created one.

Does anyone have any thing that could help me achieve this?

To summarize.

In order to make easy to identify which environment variables I should use, let's assume it will have a prefix of **SETTINGS**.
Example of how I would override values.

| **JSON PATH** | **EQUIVALENT ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE** |
| --- | --- |
| APIS.PAYMENT.BASE_URL | SETTINGS__APIS__PAYMENT__BASE_URL |
| AVAILABLELOCALES[0] | SETTINGS__AVAILABLELOCALES__0 |

Comment: Isn't it a problem in your example that '_' is a separator and also part of the name `base_url`? The variable `APIS_PAYMENT_BASE_URL` has upper case letters, the names in the json file have lower case letters. How does this fit together?

Comment: What is the notation for arrays? Please clarify the requirements a little more precisely

Comment: Maybe the [envsubst operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#envsubst-options) of [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can help you. `yq` can also process json input with the options `--input-format json` and `--output-format json`. But it works different from your described scenario. See this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/yq-utility-processing-yaml#3-variable-substitution-with-envsubst).

Comment: apparently, it isn't a problem. Normaly in Arrays it would work like: ARRAY_0_VALUE

Comment: Currently the envsubst is working well. the main problem is that, for it work properly i have to pass all environment variables. It would be nice to only override the ones i pass.

Comment: how would you know that __0 is an array index and not part of the JSON key? How would you handle keys with uppercase characters, i.e. when writing camelCase?

Comment: @TheFool I made some compromises in my answer below.  I assume that "fully numeric" portions of the environment variable are array indices.  To handle camelCase, etc., I create a "dictionary" of the keys present in the `settings.json` file and then look them up by matching while ignoring case.  There are clearly some limitations by doing this, but perhaps it works for the desired application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be solved using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).
The version is robust against settings that do not match a path in the document.

**Variables**

```
SETTINGS__APIS__PAYMENT__BASE_URL=https://example2.com
SETTINGS__AVAILABLELOCALES__0=cs
SETTINGS__UNAVAILABLE__PATH=1
```

**Code**

```bash
jq 'def settings:
      def prepareVariables:
        [$ENV | to_entries[] | select(.key | startswith("SETTINGS__"))]   # select all variables that starts with "SETTINGS__"
        | map(.key |= (. / "__" | map(tonumber? // .))[1:]);              # convert variable names to path arrays

      [paths(scalars) | [., map(ascii_upcase? // .)]] |                   # collect all leaf paths from input file and add uppercase path
      reduce .[] as $leafPath                                             # add leaf paths to corresponding settings
             (prepareVariables; map(select($leafPath[1] == .key) |= . + {path: $leafPath[0]})) |
      map(select(has("path")));                                           # drop settings for unknown paths

    . as $input |
    reduce settings[] as $setting                                         # apply new settings from variables to input file
           ($input; . | setpath($setting["path"]; $setting["value"]))
' input.json
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "apis": {
    "payment": {
      "base_url": "https://example2.com"
    },
    "order": {
      "base_url": "https://example.com/"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "authentication": {
      "authProviders": true,
      "registration": false
    }
  },
  "availableLocales": [
    "cs",
    "es"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Works great!  See it work on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/cGrDHeNCAyq).  FYI, [_"leaf_paths is an alias of paths(scalars); leaf_paths is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release."_](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#paths%2Cpaths%28node_filter%29%2Cleaf_paths).

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Thanks for the hint. I changed it in the code above. But will there ever be a new version 1.7? I hope so, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a `jq` novice, and I'd be very interested in a better `jq` script, but here's one way to use environment variables to modify a `settings.json` file.

```bash
$ cat settings.json 
{
  "apis": {
    "payment": {
      "base_url": "https://example.com/"
    },
    "order": {
      "base_url": "https://example.com/"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "authentication": {
      "authProviders": true,
      "registration": false
    }
  },
  "availableLocales": [
    "en",
    "es"
  ]
}

$ printenv|grep SETTINGS__
SETTINGS__APIS__PAYMENT__BASE_URL=https://example2.com
SETTINGS__AVAILABLELOCALES__0=cs

$ jq -n '
inputs as $i
| [ $i
    | ..
    | keys_unsorted?
    | .[]
    | strings
  ]
| unique as $allKeys
|
def fixCase:
  . as $w
  | reduce ($allKeys[]|select(length == ($w|length))) as $k
      ("";. + $k|match($w;"i").string)
;
def envpaths:
  [
    $ENV
    | to_entries[]
    | select(.key | startswith("SETTINGS__"))
    | [[ (.key|split("__"))[1:][]
         | if test("^[0-9]+$") then tonumber else fixCase end
       ],
         .value
      ]
  ]
;
reduce envpaths[] as $p ($i; .|setpath($p[0];$p[1]))' settings.json
# the output
{
  "apis": {
    "payment": {
      "base_url": "https://example2.com"
    },
    "order": {
      "base_url": "https://example.com/"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "authentication": {
      "authProviders": true,
      "registration": false
    }
  },
  "availableLocales": [
    "cs",
    "es"
  ]
}
```

See it work on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/2t8dYRCAPh6).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try to run it inside docker in a day or two and I'll mark it as a answer case it work, ok?

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade I hope it's helpful. I consider it to be a bit "fragile", in  that the environment variable names need to be formatted precisely AND the fields need to be already present in `settings.json`.  It could be modified/enhanced if you find some failing corner cases.  I hope you test it a lot.

Comment: I added another solution using `jq` because you asked for it